# XAMPP ORACLE - TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle11g, xampp

I am using `Xampp` on `Windows 8 64 bit` and using `Oracle 11g Express Edition Command line`.
I did uncomment `oci8` extension on php.ini files restart `Apache` n i am using correct password my php code is

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('system','asd','locahost/XE');
?>
```

but i am getting this error

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified in C:\xampp\htdocs\am\index.php on line 2
```

but on other pc with windows 7 its working correctly. 
My command line sql is running perfectly but php connection is not establishing.
Note:
when i was installing oracle on this pc (win8) i got an error as

The installer is unable to instantiate the file C:\Users\McLAUGH~1\AppData\Local\Temp{078E83D7-3FCC-4A72-903B-995C7CE44681}\KEY_XE.reg. The file does not appear to exist.

but i did press ok n everything seems to be fine but now this problem is happening please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the error you mentioned, please go throught the following link and follow the steps mentioned in it and try if your issue get resolved.

http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/tag/install-oracle-11g-release-xe/